# Crashlytics Android SDK - custom UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, crashlytics

Is it possible to incorporate custom UncaughtExceptionHandler along with crashlytics in one application? If yes - how?

Comment: any luck with this one? i also encountered the same issue with new relic. found out that the code was not able to chain the uncaught exception further.

Comment: @SephRemotigue try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990688/6445611

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since recent versions of Crashlytics perform initialization asynchronously, it's better to use Fabric's initialization callback:

```
private static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUEH;
private static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mCaughtExceptionHandler = 
   new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
     @Override 
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        // Custom logic goes here

        // This will make Crashlytics do its job
        mDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
};

CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
            .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(this).kits(new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(core)
            .build())
            .initializationCallback(new InitializationCallback<Fabric>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Fabric fabric) {
                    mDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
                    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mCaughtExceptionHandler);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(Exception e) {

                }
            })
            .build());
```

Comment: From what I see in CrashlyticsCore (v2.9.4), CrashlyticsController.enableExceptionHandling() is called inside onPreExecute(). So this is still being done in the same thread. Also CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler (which the controller uses) makes sure it passes the exception to whatever default handler existed. So the order of initializing Fabric and your own exception handler does not matter as long as you do the same.

Comment: I tried this in my Application class, in my case failure(Exception e) receives a callback with exception : "com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core Initialization was cancelled". Any ideas, why this would be happening ?

Comment: I'm trying this, but the InitializationCallback does not get called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 35):

**UPDATE**

Please see @kmityak [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266303/1528991) as Crashlytics/Fabric initialization is now asynchronous and my solution below is no longer valid.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can set your custom UncaughtExceptionHandler providing that it will pass exception to default UncaughtExceptionHandler to be handled later via Crashlytics.

Below code is implemented inside Application subclass:

```
private static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUEH;
private static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mCaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override 
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        // Custom logic goes here

        // This will make Crashlytics do its job
        mDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Order is important!
    // First, start Crashlytics
    Crashlytics.start(this);

    // Second, set custom UncaughtExceptionHandler
    mDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mCaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

Second option is to register Crashlytics *after* setting your custom UncaughtExceptionHandler - then all uncaught exceptions will be reported by Crashlytics as fatals, and after that passed to your custom handler.

Comment: I am not getting method `Crashlytics.start(this)`. I'm using `crashlytics:2.5.1`. I just want to exit my app as well as send report to Fabric. How can I do so ?

Comment: use `Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())` instead of `Crashlytics.start(this)`

Comment: Could you please tell me, where exactly the code belongs? I don't understand what's meant by `... inside Application subclass`. Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a custom Applicaiton class. You can do that by creating a subclass of android.app.Application and register it in AndroidManifest.xml. More information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

In your Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Crashlytics.start(this);
    initUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}

private void initUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor c = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    c.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                    // do my amazing stuff here 
                    System.err.println("Error!");
                    //then pass the job to the previous handler
                    defaultHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The reason I'm scheduling this after 5 seconds is because Crashlytics needs some time to set up his stuff. I'm using this code and it works perfectly. Of course if your app crashes on start, sorry but no custom handler ;)

Answer (score 3):

None if those solutions worked for me. I did it like following:

```
// Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
    {
        //Send Report to Crashlytics. Crashlytics will send it as soon as it starts to work
        Crashlytics.logException(e);

        //Your custom codes to Restart the app or handle this crash
        HandleCrashes(thread, e);
    }
});
```

And here is my Custom Method to restart the APP:

```
private void HandleCrashes(Thread t, Throwable e) {

    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, frmLogin.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("JustLogin", true);
    startActivity(i);

    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that Crashlytics will report this crash as Non-Fatal and not general crash.

Comment: @VitoValov is there any way around this? still send as fatal crash and also restart the app?

Answer (score 3):

1. Turn off automatic collection

   add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
     android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
     android:value="false" />
```

2. Register your custome `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

```java
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(customerUncaughtExceptionHandler)
```

3. Manually start Crashlytics after registered UncaughtExceptionHandler

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

4. rebuild and reinstall your Application

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for Fabric 2.10.1:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(yourExceptionHandler)
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        // Delegate to the default uncaught exception handler provided by the system
        Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
    }
});

// Initialize Firebase Crashlytics
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

// Set Firebase Crashlytics as the default uncaught exception handler
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().getUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: What FirebaseCrashlytics API version has `.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()`?