# Crashlytics/Fabric initializationCallback not called

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Trying to implement two crash handlers with crashlytics (as discussed in [Crashlytics Android SDK - custom UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203616/crashlytics-android-sdk-custom-uncaughtexceptionhandler?rq=1)) I can not get the intializationCalback to work - in Kotlin. Is somebody having the same issue or is there something wrong with my code?
(To clarify: neither the success nor the failure method are ever called, hence the new UncaughtException Handler is also not executed)

```
val core = CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
    .build()
Fabric.with(
    Fabric.Builder(contextProvider.invoke()).kits(
        Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(core)
            .build()
    ).initializationCallback(object : InitializationCallback<Fabric> {
        override fun success(fabric: Fabric) {
            var mDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { t, e ->
                Log.e("CrashLogger","Excpetion",e)
                mDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e)
            }
        }

        override fun failure(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("CrashLogger", "Error during initialization ", e)
        }
    }
    ).build()
)
```

Comment: Fails to work meaning `success()` get never called or your `Log.e` line never gets called upon an UE?

Comment: oops - I clarified it a bit. But methods (success and failure) are never called, hence the UE Handler is not estasblished

Comment: maybe it will sound like dumb, do the initialization works if coded in java?

Answer (score 0):

Tried almost same code in my application class but it worked for me, success() was called.

```
class MyApplication: MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val core = CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
            .build()
        Fabric.with(
            Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build())
                .initializationCallback(object: InitializationCallback<Fabric> {
                    override fun success(p0: Fabric?) {
                        Timber.d("InitializationCallback success")
                    }
                    override fun failure(p0: Exception?) {
                        Timber.d("InitializationCallback failure")
                    }
                })
                .build()
        )
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Check these

- Check `io.fabric.ApiKey` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Check if your `contextProvider.invoke()` returns appropriate context
- Try `android.app.Application` as context and see it works or not