# How to log extra data during a crash

Tags: android, crashlytics

From time to time I'm getting a `NPE` in an app I have published on Play Store and I'd like to log some extra info so I can better understand what's wrong.

Therefore I followed this guide from [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html) for enhanced reports hoping that I will see the value from a variable I log in the stack trace.

This is the code I used:

```
id = table.getId();    // <------ line that throws NPE
Crashlytics.log("userIsOnline: " + isOnline);   // <----- variable I want to know it's value
```

Today I got the stack trace from two crashes but no variable was logged. Isn't this how I should log it or is there something else I haven't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirebaseAnalytics` for log event during a crash. You can use it to log events with the `logEvent()` method.

The following example show how to log a suggested SELECT_CONTENT Event:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id)
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image")
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, 
bundle)
```

You can log your own custom events as shown in this example:

```
val params = Bundle()
params.putString("image_name", name)
params.putString("full_text", text)
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params)
```

Hope the above example will help you.

Comment: But with this code I'm logging all the time these data, right? I want to log only during a crash event.

Comment: Right, you can log an event when your crash occur.

Comment: id = table.getId();    // <------ line that throws NPE
Crashlytics.log("userIsOnline: " + isOnline);

Comment: here you can find custom crash handler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203616/crashlytics-android-sdk-custom-uncaughtexceptionhandler/26347919

Comment: But when the line with the `table.getId()` doesn't throw I'll still get an event

Comment: Have you use try.. catch block?

Comment: nope. I'll try adding a try..catch. Thanks for your answer + the link

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now and can't join the chat. I'll try adding a try..catch and the other answer to my question from another user and I'll come back later with my findings. Thanks a lot for your time, answers and your willingness to help :)

Answer (score 1):

As official docs says

> `Crashlytics.log()`  will only write to the Crashlytics crash report.

Use it above `id = table.getId();` and check data in Non-Fatals tab in Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

```
Log non-fatal exceptions
In addition to automatically reporting your app’s crashes, Crashlytics lets you log non-fatal exceptions.

On Android, that means you can log caught exceptions in your app’s catch blocks:

try {
    methodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
    // handle your exception here
}
```