# Upgrade Firebase Crashlytics with custom UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

While working on `Update your apps to use latest Firebase Crashlytics SDKs before November 15, 2020`, After i activate my custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, it won't send crash to Crashlytics anymore.

Below code i set it inside `onCreate()` of `Application`.

```
        FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
        crashlytics.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG); // only release able to send.
        crashlytics.sendUnsentReports(); // send reports
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e); // record exception.
            // below things are restart app when crash appeared.
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
            if (intent != null) {
                ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
                Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
            }
        });
```

When I remove custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, it is able to report to Crashlytics.

Below code is working perfectly when using Fabric library. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266303/4316327)

```
        CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();
        Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(this).kits(new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(core).build()).initializationCallback(new InitializationCallback<Fabric>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Fabric fabric) {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
                    LogWrapper.logException(e);
                    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
                    if (intent != null) {
                        ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
                        Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).build());
```

Any solution on this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank alot.

Comment: Got the same issue

Comment: @Truong Hieu: Did you fix this issue? I am having the same issue. If yes, Could you please provide how you did it? Thanks

Comment: @ItayFeldman: did you fix this? and how?

Comment: @nibz no not yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is posted [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2005). I'll paste my modified code here for anyone who looking for it:

Below code is written in Java. For Kotlin, please visit the original post.

```
public class NewCrashHandlerContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final String TAG = "NewCrashHandler";
    static long PRE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000L;
    static long POST_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000L;

    public static void initializeAfterFirebaseContentProvider() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new PreFirebaseCrashHandler(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "+onCreate()");
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new PostFirebaseCrashHandler(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()));
            return true;
        }finally {
            Log.i(TAG, "-onCreate()");
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }


    static class PreFirebaseCrashHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler previousUncaughtExceptionHandler;
        public static final String TAG = "PreFirebaseCrashHandler";

        public PreFirebaseCrashHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler previousUncaughtExceptionHandler) {
            this.previousUncaughtExceptionHandler = previousUncaughtExceptionHandler;
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread t, @NonNull Throwable e) {
            LogWrapper.logException(e);
            try {
                // my own logic
                Thread.sleep(PRE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                LogWrapper.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
            } finally {
                previousUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t,e);
            }
        }
    }

    static class PostFirebaseCrashHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler previousUncaughtExceptionHandler;
        public static final String TAG = "PostFirebaseCrashHandler";

        public PostFirebaseCrashHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler previousUncaughtExceptionHandler) {
            this.previousUncaughtExceptionHandler = previousUncaughtExceptionHandler;
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread t, @NonNull Throwable e) {
            LogWrapper.e(TAG, "+uncaughtException($thread, $throwable)");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(POST_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                LogWrapper.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
            }finally {
                previousUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t,e);
            }
            LogWrapper.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

In Application file, write in `onCreate()` method:

```
NewCrashHandlerContentProvider.initializeAfterFirebaseContentProvider();
```

Also don't forget to update `manifests`

```
<provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:name=".utils.NewCrashHandlerContentProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="101"
            android:grantUriPermissions="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call getUncaughtExceptionHandler and hang onto it, and then set your own uncaughtexceptionhandler and call ours back before you exit.

Comment: Tried to implement this and didn't work.
Could you provide an example?

Comment: ```
val previous = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
  ...
  previous?.uncaughtException(t, e)
});
```

Comment: @swooby Thanks for your comment, it's exactly how I've done it but still no crashes in the dashboard

Comment: @ItayFeldman: Were you able to solve this? I am facing similar issue. I do not see crashes for release build in dashboard

Comment: @Oleg Kodysh: Could you please elaborate on how I should do it? thanks

Comment: @nibz Not yet, I'm waiting for firebase's support team to get back to me on the issue